# python multiprocessing pool.map not blocking?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize some web requests in python using `multiprocessing`, but it appears that occasionally, all of the functions I send to `map` do not complete.

These results appear whether I'm using python 2 or 3.

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import multiprocessing

def my_print(string):
    print(string)

all_strings = ["alpaca", "bear", "cat", "dog", "elephant", "frog"]

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
pool.map(my_print, all_strings)
```

I run it like so:

```
for i in `seq 1 50`; do ./test.py | wc -l; done | sort | uniq -c
```

And my results will look like:

```
6 5
44 6
```

...so most of the time all 6 executions of the function are running, but occasionally, only 5 of them will run until the overall script completes execution. I expect there to be `50 6` as a result (aka, all functions getting executed on every run).

The documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map says `It blocks until the result is ready.` I assumed that to mean `All functions will complete before we move to the next line of code`.

Am I misunderstanding that? Does using a pool require you to always call `pool.close()` and `pool.join()` to ensure the tasks are complete?

Edit: I'm running on AWS, if that makes any obvious difference - a coworker told me I should mention that.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

All workers run their functions and return any values before `map` returns. That is true. But that doesn't mean you will see all strings immediately.

You have multiple worker processes trying to write to the same file/terminal. To make that work you might have to `import sys` and call `sys.stdout.flush()` after every `print()` in the worker process.

Comment: I see. So does mean that `pool.close(); pool.join()` at the end of the script (which makes it fully run everything every time) waits for all subprocesses to finish, which implies a stdout `flush()` ?